# Closed Xml not open excel file in server

Tags: c#, closedxml

I have used closed-XML 0.75 version dll and uploaded on the server, It works good on local but on the server, it throws a File Format exception. When I open the file in open xml sdk productivity tool 2.5, it shows that ExtendedFilePropertiesPart is missing.

```
Stream fileStream = null;
try
{
    fileStream = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(FilePath));
    var _xlWorkBook = new ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorkbook(fileStream);
    return _xlWorkBook;
}
catch (FileFormatException ex)
{
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Not completly sure right now, but I think you need to add atleast one worksheet to the workbook, A workbook without any worksheets is not valid.

Comment: The workbook has two worksheet. So worksheet is not an issue.

Comment: How did you upload the file? Perhaps it was corrupted during upload? Did you try opening the uploaded file in Excel?

Comment: The file is uploaded on amazon server, i have downloaded it and checked on local, it shows ExtendedFilePropertiesPart is missing.